# How to duplicate a section in Mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp

I'm creating a template on mailchimp and I would like to add sections to it. 
For now it is divided in "subheader/header/body/..."
I would like to add another section, so I will be able to change the background color just on this section.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new template, it is all going to be dependent of the Template selected. We would have two options to select from and will mention below.

First option:

Change the background color from within the 'Design' portion of your Campaign builder; in doing so it will in turn change the background color for the particular section your content has been placed into (Pre-header, Header, Body, Footer.)

Shown here: https://cl.ly/240q1V333D1p

Second Option:

If you are wanting to place additional text and only wanting to change the background color for the content within the block, you will want to use a 'Boxed Text Content Block'. This will be the only content block that will allow for the background color to be styled for this content block.

Shown here; blue content block: https://cl.ly/0z2Y213E3A32

This article will provide a bit more detail on how to use our Boxed Text Content Block here:

Use Boxed Text Content Blocks: http://eepurl.com/b2Q761